# Clone divs, then fill them with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, frontend

with the aim to speed-up my prototyping phase, I want to clone my divs and then fill them with some content stored into an array.

Here is some generic content who needs to be cloned:

```
<li class="shots--li">
  <img class="image" src="images/dribbble.png">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
</li>
```

I already know how to clone:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var shots = $('.shots--li');
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        shots.clone().insertAfter(shots);
    }
});
```

Now my problem is, how can I replace the content of my clones?
I imagine arrays like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img_src = [
        "http://placehold.it/50x60",
        "http://placehold.it/50x70",
        "http://placehold.it/50x80"
    ];
    var img_src_array = img_src.split(',');
    $.each(img_src_array, function(key,value) {
        $('.shots--li img').append.html(value);
    });
    var title_h1 = [
        "Some title",
        "Another title",
        "A Title?"
    ];
    var title_h1_array = title_h1.split(',');
    $.each(title_h1_array, function(key,value) {
        $('.shots--li h1').append(value);
    });
    var paragraph_p = [
        "Some description",
        "Another description",
        "A Description?"
    ];
    var paragraph_p_array = paragraph_p.split(',');
    $.each(paragraph_p_array, function(key,value) {
        $('.shots--li p').append(value);
    });
});
```

Update: here is my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uniko/w53dbyns/2/)

I really don't know if there is a simple way guys nor if my question fill the stackoverflow rules but since I never worked with arrays and clones at the same time… it would be great to have your thoughts.
Thanks!

Comment: `img_src` is already an array, you don't need to use `split()`.

Comment: Is your question about how to manipulate the contents of the clones, or identify the clones you created so you can manipulate them?

Comment: Approach is very disconnected.  One loop of data ,create and update a clone and append ...done. You aren't indexing incidents with your approach

Comment: Yeah, if possible, do your clone and manipulation all in one step before appending to the body.  Better yet, if you know your going to be doing a batch of them, do all of them, store them in a fragment object, and append that to the body at the very end to minimize dom interactions.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for all your correction it surely helped me a lot!

Comment: @Taplar, the question was more about how to manipulate the content of the clones and Barmar already corrected me for good and now, I'll give Dan's answer a try even if I don't understand it all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `$(".shots--li <element>").append()`, you're appending to *all* the LIs, not just one of them. You need to select just one at a time, which you can do with `.eq()`. You're also using `append` incorrectly -- you can't append to an image, because it doesn't have child elements. You need to set its `src` attribute to the image URL. And for the other element type, you probably want to use `.html()` to replace the contents, rather than `.append()`.

```
$.each(img_src, function(i, value) {
    $(".shots--li img").eq(i).attr("src", value);
});

$.each(title_h1, function(i, value) {
    $(".shots--li h1").eq(i).html(value);
});

$.each(paragraph_p, function(i, value) {
    $(".shots--li p").eq(i).html(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do the entire process programmatically. It will make the process of inserting your example content a lot easier.

```
function makeExampleItem(src, title, description) {
  var $li = $('<li class="shots--li"></li>'),
      $img = $('<img class="image"></img>'),
      $h1 = $('<h1></h1>'),
      $p = $('<p></p>');

  $img.attr('src', src);
  $h1.html(title);
  $p.html(description);

  return $li
    .append($img)
    .append($h1)
    .append($p);
}
```

Then you can loop over your example data and create an item for each bit.

I would suggest condensing it into a single list.

```
var examples = [
  {
    src: 'http://placehold.it/50x60',
    title: 'Some title',
    description: 'Some description'
  },
  {
    src: 'http://placehold.it/50x60',
    title: 'Some title',
    description: 'Some description'
  }
];
```

Then we simply loop over it, create a `<li>` for each item and then insert it into a `<ul>` somewhere.

```
var $ul = $('#my-ul');

examples.forEach(function(example) {
  var $li = makeExampleItem(example.src, example.title, example.description);
  $ul.append($li);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dan-prince, I'm not sure to understand it completely but I'll give it a try since it looks really interesting and easier to read.

Comment: No problem, the general idea is that we make our HTML using Javascript and we make it using our example data, rather than writing it in HTML, cloning the element and then trying to insert the example data in afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Dan I understand, it's just that I build my html inside a design app (macaw) and I can't use only js for my html.

Comment: You don't have to use only JS for all your HTML, just this small section that you want to clone.

Answer (score 0):

Just some observation:

1. Your model is a bit weird... Unless it really need to be in 3 arrays, I'd choose an array of object literal instead like:

   `var entries = [ 
      { imgSrc: '...', title: '...', content: '...' }, 
      { imgSrc: '...', title: '...', content: '...' }, 
      { ... }
   ];`
2. Cloning and replacing individual nodes the way you do it is also slow.  You should consider creating all the template elements in memory and do the content substitutions there first and finally attach all of them to an in memory container and finally attach that container to the DOM as a batch since this will be more performance.  Something that Dan Price suggested, but I'd delay that ul element insertion event longer so it's a batch. See: http://jsfiddle.net/jchandra/w4jp4qto/ or http://jsfiddle.net/jchandra/kpm3tz39/, was playing around w/ large amount of data (4000 rows and 8 columns).  Sort of similar to what you are trying to achieve... in vanilla JS.
3. Tons of libraries / frameworks have solve this template content substitution problem such as [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or [angular](https://angularjs.org/), and others.  It's probably worth it to look that over.  Most of them comes w/ interactive tutorials that will walk you through this type of things.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy for your help, that's some really interesting scripts. I'll surely take a look.